# How to install php-gtk in the Acer Aspire One?

Tags: php, fedora, php-gtk

I have an application that works pretty well in Ubuntu, Windows and the Xandros that come with the Asus EeePC.

Now we are moving to the [Acer Aspire One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspire_One) but I'm having a lot of trouble making php-gtk to compile under the Fedora-like (Linpus Linux Lite) Linux that come with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Guys well I finally got this thing to work the basic workflow was this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum install yum-utils
#We don't want to update the main gtk2 by mistake so we download them
#manually and install with no-deps[1](and forced because gtk version
#version of AA1 and the gtk2-devel aren't compatible).
sudo yumdownloader --disablerepo=updates gtk2-devel glib2-devel
sudo rpm --force --nodeps -i gtk2*rpm glib2*rpm

#We install the rest of the libraries needed.
sudo yum --disablerepo=updates install atk-devel pango-devel libglade2-devel
sudo yum install php-cli php-devel make gcc

#We Download and compile php-gtk
wget http://gtk.php.net/do_download.php?download_file=php-gtk-2.0.1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf php-gtk-2.0.1.tar.gz
cd php-gtk-2.0.1
./buildconf
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If you want to add more libraries like gtk-extra please type `./configure -help` before making it to see the different options available.

After installing you'll need to add `php_gtk2.so` to the *Dynamic Extensions* of `/etc/php.ini`

```
extension=php_gtk2.so
```

Sources:

[1]: [Dependency problems on Acer Aspire One Linux](http://macles.blogspot.com/2008/08/dependency-problems-on-acer-aspire-one.html)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get all components needed for Phoronix test suite installed on Fedora but still have one issue.

```
# phoronix-test-suite gui
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/phoronix-test-suite: line 28: [: /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite: unary operator expected
```

You need two packages that aren't in Fedora, php-gtk, but php-gtk also has it's dependency - pecl-cairo

php-gtk needs to be downloaded from svn because tar.gz version is really old and doesn't work with php 5.3

Here is how I got all components built.

```
su -c "yum install php-cli php-devel make gcc gtk2-devel svn"

svn co http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/cairo/trunk pecl-cairo
cd pecl-cairo/
phpize
./configure
make
su -c "make install"

cd ..

svn co http://svn.php.net/repository/gtk/php-gtk/trunk php-gtk
cd php-gtk
./buildconf
./configure
make
su -c "make install"

cd ..

wget http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/download.php?file=phoronix-test-suite-2.8.1
tar xvzf phoronix-test-suite-2.8.1.tar.gz
cd phoronix-test-suite
su -c "./install-sh"
```

So please take where I left to get Phoronix test suite running on Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

If you could give us more to go on than just trouble making it compile; we might be better able to help you with your issues.

Comment: Yeah i was just thinking that, My first approach with this question was to leave a nice how-to page. I'll ask again with an specific problem and after resolve that and compile successfully, I'll go back to this page and make that nice how-to with the whole process not just the problem.